# why doesnt sys.py in my current directory break "import sys"

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python and was reading about how python goes about looking for modules when import statement is invoked. It appears that when doing stuff on the python interactive prompt, it should look for sys.py in my current working directory first when I do "import sys" but it seems to be saving me from this mistake somehow. When I do a dir(sys) after I invoke import sys it shows me the correct names even though i put a bogus sys.py in the CWD.

Could someone please kindly explain what's happening?

Comment: I just have this in my bogus sys.py: "from sys import exit"

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sys` module is **built in** to the python interpreter and thus has higher priority over your bogus python module. Additionally, before any of your code is run, some part of the python startup has already imported the sys module and cached it in `sys.modules`. If a module you try to import is in the cache, the cached module is returned regardless of anything else.

Comment: many thanks everyone. and sorry for asking a dumb question. No excuse but the book (Learning python 5th edition p678) i was reading doesnt mention the built-in modules being considered first and i didnt ask google the right questions. on a related note, whats the best way to find the modules built into the interpreter? I saw another stackoverflow comment that suggested sys.builtin_module_names is the comprehensive list but doesnt appear to be because os is not on that list and I cant seem to break that either by creating os.py.

Comment: @sprizes `os` is not a builtin module, it is in fact coded in pure python. The reason you cannot hijack it is beacuse the `os` module has already been imported and cached in the python startup process.